# Angular Directive - how to setup bi-directional binding with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive for redactor (a wysiwyg editor). It works after some hacking but I would like find out the right way. The main challenge for me is the bi-directional binding between the ng-model and the redactor jquery plugin. I listen to keyup and command event from the wysiwyg editor and update the model. I also watch for model change from outside the redactor editor so that I can update the redactor editor accordingly. The tricky part is: How do I ignore the ng-model change imposed by the reactor editor (from the first half of the binding)?

In the following code, it remembers the last value the redactor editor updates to the model and ignore model change if the new value of the model equals to that last value. I am really not sure if this is the right way to achieve this. It seems to me that this is a common problem with bi-directional binding in Angular and there must be a ***right*** way. Thanks!

```
<textarea ui-redactor='{minHeight: 500}' ng-model='content'></textarea>
```

directive.coffee (sorry for the coffeescript)

```
angular.module("ui.directives").directive "uiRedactor", ->

  require: "ngModel"
  link: (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) ->
    redactor = null
    updatedVal = null

    updateModel = ->
      ngModel.$setViewValue updatedVal = elm.val()
      scope.$apply()

    options =
      execCommandCallback: updateModel
      keydownCallback: updateModel
      keyupCallback: updateModel

    optionsInAttr = if attrs.uiRedactor then scope.$eval(attrs.uiRedactor) else {}

    angular.extend options, optionsInAttr

    setTimeout ->
      redactor = elm.redactor options

    #watch external model change
    scope.$watch attrs.ngModel, (newVal) ->
      if redactor? and updatedVal isnt newVal
        redactor.setCode(ngModel.$viewValue or '')
        updatedVal = newVal
```

Comment: Instead of $watch(), have you tried to implement ngModel.$render()?  It seems that $render() will only be called if something inside Angular changes the model.  In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/SKgVS/), $render() is only called when I click on the link (which changes the model programatically).  (Since I don't have a redactor license I can't test this.)

Comment: Great, glad it worked, and thanks for letting us know.

Comment: I'm using this directive and works good for binding, except one problem. The last change (be it key press/paste or anything) is not binded until another keypress. So it's always one step behind. (all callbacks are executed corectly)

Comment: yeah this is not working any more. the fiddle doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Rajcok gave the solution (Thank you!) The trick is to use ngModel.$render() rather than $watch().

use

```
ngModel.$render = ->
  redactor?.setCode(ngModel.$viewValue or '')
```

instead of

```
scope.$watch attrs.ngModel, (newVal) ->
  if redactor? and updatedVal isnt newVal
    redactor.setCode(ngModel.$viewValue or '')
    updatedVal = newVal
```

Comment: ng-model defined in the template does not update using this directive? Have any idea why?